# Best way to design an architecture for an online web, android, windows and ios application in .Net

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, windows

My requirement is to design an software architecture for an online application, which will be hosted on web (both desktop and mobile browser), windows phone, android and iOS. So please suggest me a design in which most of the part can be used commonly to support all these client APIs. I want to develop this in .Net technologies.

Comment: Bootstrap is the most common way to do this!

Comment: Can you please elaborate this in more detail?

Comment: you could check this link: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Question is exactly what I'm looking, so may I know why downgraded?

Comment: I am not downgrade, but your question not meet SO question rule: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Checking help center for more information, friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you technologies:

1. ASP.NET MVC
2. Web API
3. Bootstrap  - for layout design
4. AngularJS/Knockout 
   Rest up to you.........

Comment: Ok great, but how my design will handle android, ios and windows phone client app?

Comment: I would suggest once you should read this post: [Hybrid-Mobile-Apps-MVC](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Hybrid-Mobile-Apps-MVC)